# trying to make this program work below but always get undefined when i use .lenght

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, selectors-api

```js
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){

    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    function handleClick(){
       alert("i Got Clicked");
    }
}
console.log(numberOfDrumButtons.lenght);
```

whenever I run this command I get undefined as an answer in the console log.

This is a program that shows how many buttons are there in the program but the `.lenght` feature doesn't seem to work for me .

Comment: I thought "lenght" is a typo until I saw this thrice in your question. It's length not lenght

Answer (score 1):

Basically you had a spelling mistake: "lenght" should be "length".

```js
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons.length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

function handleClick() {
  alert("i Got Clicked");
}

console.log(numberOfDrumButtons.length);
```

```html
<button>B1</button>
<button>B2</button>
<button>B3</button>
<button>B4</button>
```

Comment: Don't post answers for typos. Leave a comment and then flag the question to be closed. As there is a specific flag for issues caused by typos.